# compling error on mips sde5 with cygwin

Tags: c++, cygwin, mips

i compile this code using mips sde5 on cygwin but it dowesnt make any elf file
please help me
it says

> $ /usr/local/sde5/bin/sde-g++.exe -mcpu=r3000 -EL mult.cpp -o mult.elf
>   mult.cpp:52:2: warning: no newline at end of file
>   /usr/local/sde5/lib/gcc-lib/sde/2.96-sdemips-030211/../../../../sde/bin/ld:
>   warn ing: cannot find entry symbol __start; defaulting to
>   0000000080020000
>   /cygdrive/c/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/cczcsdCQ.o: In function
>   `main':
>   /cygdrive/c/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/cczcsdCQ.o(.text+0x1dc):
>   undefined r eference to`memcpy'
>   /cygdrive/c/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/cczcsdCQ.o(.text+0x1fc):
>   undefined r eference to `memcpy' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

```
    void mul(int A[16][16],int B[16][16],int C[16][16])
{
    int i,j,k;
    for(i=0;i<16;i++)
        for(j=0;j<16;j++)
        {
            C[i][j]=0;
            for(k=0;k<16;k++)
                C[i][j]+=A[i][k]*B[k][j];
        }
}

int main()
{
    int A[16][16]={  1,0,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,5,5,1,0,0,3 ,
                     1,4,4,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,4,2,1,5,2,2 ,
                     6,0,0,1,2,8,2,0,0,0,5,5,1,0,0,3 ,
                     2,7,0,0,1,2,3,2,1,0,6,4,1,0,6,6 ,
                     3,0,7,0,1,2,2,0,0,0,5,5,1,0,0,3 ,
                     1,0,0,0,0,5,2,0,0,0,8,9,1,8,0,5 ,
                     0,0,1,1,0,2,2,0,0,0,5,5,1,0,0,3 ,
                     1,0,5,5,0,2,2,0,5,0,5,5,1,8,0,4 ,
                     1,0,0,0,0,2,2,0,9,0,5,5,1,0,0,3 ,
                     1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 ,
                     2,0,2,0,3,1,1,0,0,5,6,2,1,0,0,0 ,
                     1,0,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,5,5,1,0,0,3 ,
                     3,0,7,0,1,2,2,0,0,0,5,5,1,0,0,3 ,
                     1,0,0,0,0,5,2,0,0,0,8,9,1,8,0,5 ,
                     0,0,1,1,0,2,2,0,0,0,5,5,1,0,0,3 ,                  
                     3,3,3,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0 };

    int B[16][16]={  3,0,7,0,1,2,2,0,0,0,5,5,1,0,0,3 ,
                     0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 ,
                     6,0,0,1,2,8,2,0,0,0,5,5,1,0,0,3 ,
                     2,7,0,0,1,2,3,2,1,0,6,4,1,0,6,6 ,
                     1,4,4,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,4,2,1,5,2,2 ,
                     3,3,3,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0 ,
                     0,0,1,1,0,2,2,0,0,0,5,5,1,0,0,3 ,
                     0,0,5,5,0,2,2,0,5,0,5,5,1,8,0,4 ,
                     0,0,0,0,0,2,2,0,9,0,5,5,1,0,0,3 ,
                     0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 ,
                     0,0,2,0,3,1,1,0,0,5,6,2,1,0,0,0 ,
                     0,0,0,0,0,2,2,0,9,0,5,5,1,0,0,3 ,
                     0,0,7,0,1,2,2,0,0,0,5,5,1,0,0,3 ,
                     1,0,0,0,0,5,2,0,0,0,8,9,1,8,0,5 ,
                     0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 ,                  
                     1,0,5,5,0,2,2,0,5,0,5,5,1,8,0,4 };
    int C[16][16];
    mul(A,B,C);

    return 0;
}
```

regards

Comment: Did you include `stdio.h` and `string.h` ?

Comment: Looks like you haven't got/compiled can't find the C runtime library. run `$(CROSS_COMPILE)g++ -v` to see where it is looking and add `-L path` to add library locations to look in.

Comment: i add this to my code   
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>   but there is no difference, same error